# Send data with SPMD in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

In Matlab (2012b), is there a way to halt one thread created by SPMD before it send data? because thread 2 have only a finite size of buffer to accept data from thread 1, and according to matlab, labSend() will return before the data transfer completes, which means in theory thread 1 can keep sending data to thread 2 until the system run out of memory:

What I want to do is something like this:

```
 spmd (2)

  if labindex==1
    %...
    if (BufferAtLab2isNotFull)
        labSend(data, 2);
    end
    %...
  elseif labindex==2
    if (BufferNotFull)
      labReceive(data, 1);
    end
    %...

  end
 end
```

In C/C++ it is pretty easy to do that with shared-memory multithreading, but in matlab it seems it is quite hard since there is no shared resource to check from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want lab 1 to wait after each `labSend` until lab 2 has finished it's `labRecieve`, then simple add in a `labBarrier` to each which will cause lab 1 to wait until all threads have reached that point.

```
spmd (2)
  if labindex==1
    %...
    if (BufferAtLab2isNotFull)
      labSend(data, 2);
    end
    labBarrier;
    %...
  elseif labindex==2
    labSend(bufSize,1);
    %...
    if (BufferNotFull)
      labReceive(data, 1);
    end
    labBarrier;
    %...
  end
end
```

If you are concerned about Lab 1 sending too much in a single labSend you can always have lab 2 first send it's buffer size.